# Using hover on video element

Tags: html, css

I have recently added a video to the front of my page. There are 5 images that have a button showing when you hover over, but the video does not seem to work.

Here is the site you can watch it on: www.barsnes.tk

Here is my Html code:

```
  <section class="portfolio_home" id="portfolio">
        <figure class="port-item">
            <!-- Portfolio 1 -->
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/eBRYWII.png" alt="portfolio item"/> 
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <a href="Geo.html" class="button_accent">Geofilters</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="port-item">
            <!-- Portfolio 5 -->
        <video src="Torsken-Intro.mp4" alt="portfolio item" autoplay loop/> 
            <figcaption class="port-desc">
                <a href="Video.html" class="button_accent">Videos</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

Here is my css code:

```
/* portfolio
*/

.portfolio_home {
    margin: 1.8em 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.portfolio_home img {
    padding: 0;
}

.portfolio_home video {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.port-item video {
    display: block;
}

.port-item {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.port-desc {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.port-desc p {
    margin: .5em;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
    .port-item {
        width: 33.3333334%;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden
    }

    .port-desc {
        transform: translateY(150%);
    }

    .port-item:hover .port-desc {
        transform: translateY(0%)
    }

    .port-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    .port-item video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
    }

}

.button_accent {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .8rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFF;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    color: #FFF;
}

.button_accent:hover,
.button_accent:focus {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

Quite a bit of code have been removed, but if you want to see it as a whole, take a look here, https://github.com/Barsnes/Barsnes

Any help is appreciated, and also, remember to add amn explanation to what I have done wrong!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a VERY easy solution to this problem: Close your video tag :P

Video tags aren't like image tags, they need to be closed. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zen5c706/1/) of your site, with the fixed tag.

Code snippet:

```
<video src="Torsken-Intro.mp4" alt="portfolio item" autoplay loop></video> 
        <figcaption class="port-desc">
            <a href="Video.html" class="button_accent">Videos</a>
        </figcaption>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! It's an easy oversight to make :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting example about something similar https://codepen.io/gil--/pen/bNxZWg

The secret is the javascript, specifically these two functions:

```
function hoverVideo(e) {  
    $('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overlay to your video like -

```
<figure class="port-item">
    <!-- Portfolio 5 -->
    <div id="video-overlay"></div>
    <video src="Torsken-Intro.mp4" alt="portfolio item" autoplay loop/> 
    <figcaption class="port-desc port-vid-desc">
        <a href="Video.html" class="button_accent">Videos</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

with the CSS

```
#video-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Set height to your liking */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

and add `:hover` functionality to it.